# Decode / unescape XML in JSONP response

Tags: jquery, xml, escaping, jsonp

I'm trying to deliver an XML file to a PhoneGap app.
I've already gone through setting up a JSONP XML response on my server. 
I'm using jQuery via

```
 $.get(url, function (data) {//dostuff}, "jsonp xml");
```

The problem is that the XML is fairly complex, and has quotes and apostrophe's in it. 
My first inclination was to use Apache Commons

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavascript(myxmlString);
```

But I'm not sure how to unescape it when I get it back.

I tried

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(myXml);
```

and then

```
var decoded = $("<div/>").html(data).text();
```

But that's not really working either, I'm guessing because the XML doesn't really work perfectly as HTML. As it contains things like `<![CDATA[XXX]]>`

So the question is how do I escape/unescape my xml for a cross-domain jsonp request?
Just escape and unescape the quotes alone?

I'm happy to entertain any thoughts or solutions.

Comment: Uhm, what does the JSON look like, and how is the XML embedded in the JSON ?

Comment: ' jQuery21009981509427858087_1394835805655("<?xmlversion=\"1.0\"encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>..."); ' Javascript escaped at the moment, but I'd like to know the best way to escape/unescape the xml portion.

Comment: So you're passing XML as JSON, and it's escaped. That happens with JSON as well, but JSON.parse unescapes it, but I suppose that doesn't work with XML, so I really have no idea, I've never really seen XML being passed that way before.

Comment: Well, after a fair bit of research, it doesn't appear terribly uncommon. From what I can surmise using "jsonp xml" as your data type is set up for this specific purpose. A simple xml file such as "<tag>sometext</tag>" seems to work fine.